# js plotly heat map always upsidown?

Tags: javascript, arrays, plotly, plotly.js

I'm using plotly js' heatmap to show every third year of an ocean surface temperature dataset. The issue is that no matter what technique I use to reverse the order of data going into the plotting call, the canvas always shows the plot upsidown.

[upsidown heatmap](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8FQWh.png)

My code is at https://alpha.iodide.io/notebooks/3899/?viewMode=report, and with the [data.json](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1GJaDbYkv-wq6bzqn741AR_wrfzZZ0DbH/view?usp=sharing) attached here the resulting picture can be found for yourself by uploading the data.json to the notebook page.

Answer (score 0):

Could be a browser issue. From Chrome looks normal. [image]